# DjangoRestFramework HTTPS Links With Routers and Viewsets

Tags: django, ssl, https, django-rest-framework

Is there an easy way to modify the links out-of-the-box for viewsets and routers?

For example, in urls.py:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, routers
...
class Activity_TypeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Activity_Type
...
router.register(r'activity_types', Activity_TypeViewSet)
...
url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
```

This sets up url structure like:

```
{"activity_types": "http://odd.quantdevgroup.com/activity_types/"}
```

The question comes down to how easy it is to make the link:

```
{"activity_types": "**https**://odd.quantdevgroup.com/activity_types/"}
```

If I deactivated http/ port 80 and only allowed https/ port 443 then my app requires manually adding https to the link after it fails to open http (because I disabled port 80).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

DRF [reverse](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/reverse.py) uses `request.build_absolute_uri(url)` to generate urls which will build URLs ["using the server variables available in this request."](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri), so if the request is http, generated URLs will be HTTP and same thing for HTTPS.

If your django app running behind a reverse proxy, then you need to configure [SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header) setting.

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

***However, you have to be really careful when setting this:***

> ### Warning
>
> **You will probably open security holes in your site if you set this
>   without knowing what you’re doing. And if you fail to set it when you
>   should. Seriously.**
>
> Make sure ALL of the following are true before setting this (assuming
>   the values from the example above):
>
> Your Django app is behind a proxy. Your proxy strips the
>   **`X-Forwarded-Proto`** header from all incoming requests. In other words,
>   if end users include that header in their requests, the proxy will
>   discard it. Your proxy sets the **`X-Forwarded-Proto`** header and sends it
>   to Django, but only for requests that originally come in via HTTPS. If
>   any of those are not true, you should keep this setting set to **`None`**
>   and find another way of determining HTTPS, perhaps via custom
>   middleware.

For nginx, you can set `X-Forwarded-Proto` header using this configuration:

```
location / {
    # ... 
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Comment: That is what I needed.  If anyone else is looking specifically at EC2/Elastic Beanstalk [GETTING A DJANGO APP TO USE HTTPS ON AWS ELASTIC BEANSTALK](http://rickchristianson.wordpress.com/2013/10/31/getting-a-django-app-to-use-https-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk/).  The update to that article [UPDATING WSGI AUTOMATICALLY IN AMAZON AWS](http://rickchristianson.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/updating-wsgi-automatically-in-amazon-aws/) was the steps I was missing.

Comment: Should also add `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True` and
`CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True`