# Django REST Framework pagination links do not use HTTPS

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm setting up pagination for a certain DRF endpoint that works well- however when deployed on my server, which uses HTTPS, the links to the next & previous pages are formed with `http://` instead of `https://`. This causes the requests for next/previous pages to be blocked by the browser.

I've double checked that the initial request was issued, with HTTPS, and the 2nd answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097643/django-rest-framework-https-for-absolute-urls) states that it should be using HTTPS in the formed URLs since the request came over HTTPS.

The first answer to that same question didn't help either- I added the `X-Forwarded-Proto` line to my nginx config and reloaded, to no avail.

[The DRF docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/reverse/) mention that reverse() should behave as the base Django reverse, however it seems pretty clear that the initial request is HTTPS while the returned URL is HTTP.

Here are a couple screenshots that show the initial request (`https://<domain>.com/api/leaderboard/`):

[image]

With the response containing `next: http://<domain>.com/api/leaderboard/?page=2`):

[image]

I figured this would be a simple setting, but haven't been able to find anything after searching both this site and the DRF site.

This is my nginx configuration:

```
 location / {
    # proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9900;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';

    root /opt/app/client/dist;
    index index.html index.htm;

}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279893/djangorestframework-https-links-with-routers-and-viewsets) contains a pretty detailed answer, but ultimately says that urls are formed with the same protocol as the request, which doesn't seem to be the case here. Do I need to set that Django SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER? I wasn't sure, given the warning that it's potentially insecure.

Comment: I should give 2 points to this question. thank you

Comment: Hi have you solved this problem? I got same issue with you, the base url is fine, yet addin g "page=" it force redirect to http.

Answer (score 31):

Since this is the first SO post that comes up in google search result, I think it would be useful to share how I solved it. Mine has a Kubernetes flavor, but under the hood the logic is not so different than the others.

I'm using Kubernetes ingress controller sitting in front of Django, so things might be different to you, but I'll summarize my context so you can see if it's useful to you:

### The Problem

So I got the same issue as OP, the pagination link from DRF is always `http` even if I'm hitting the api endpoint using `https`. You can see this more clear if you have setup the browser API which comes with the Django REST Framework (DRF), and go to the api root page. I see all links that's generated by DRF are all `http` regardless of what protocol I use when visiting the site.

### My Context

The stack, by order from external world till Django:

1. Kuberenetes Nginx Ingress Controller (w/ SSL setup using letsencrypt)
2. Ingress rule points to Django service
3. Gunicorn starts the Django server
4. Django reads the `settings.py` and start serving requests

### How I Debug and Found out the Cause

1. Dump `nginx.conf` of the ingress controller. In case you don't know how to to this: first figure out the pod name by `kuberctl get pods -n <namespace of your ingress controller>`, write that name down, then dump the file by `kubectl exec -it -n ingress_controller_namespace ingress_controller_pod_name cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf > nginx.conf`.
2. Look at the `nginx.conf`, check if you have `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` in the `location` section for your website domain, or similar thing that sets the proxy header `X-Forwarded-Proto` properly. By default, the Kubernetes nginx ingress controller should already have this line (or the equivalent) for you.
3. Next the request is directed to Gunicorn. One gotcha is you will want to add `--forwarded-allow-ips="*"` to your gunicorn command, or if you know your nginx server IP, you can limit down to that one, so that gunicorn will forward the headers for you, otherwise gunicorn will strip off those headers. So you end up with command like `gunicorn django_server.wsgi:application --forwarded-allow-ips="*" --workers=${PROPER_WORKER_NUM} --log-level info --bind 0.0.0.0:8001`. You can have 4 workers by specifying `workers=4`, usually depends on the CPU you have on the server. The `--log-level info` is just for debug purpose, it's optional.
4. In Django, you will need to have `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')` in `settings.py`, which other answer has mentioned. You may wonder why the prefix `HTTP_` while in nginx our header name is `X-Forwarded-Proto`. This is because WSGI will add the prefix to headers that it recognizes. This line basically says, if the header `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` equals to the string `"https"`, then Django recognizes the request as secure. This will affect several behaviors in Django, e.g. you will get `request.is_secure == True`, `request.build_absolute_uri(None) == 'https://...'`, and most important, Django REST Framework pagination link will now use `https`! (As long as you indeed hit the api by `https`)

Alright, now you can test again. If DRF gives you https now - congrats. Or, if you are same as me, after trying above, still no luck - DRF still generating the damn `http` links. I want to share some tipbits when I was debugging like hell:

Print out the following values in Django, either by `print()`, if you have `DEBUG=True` and have access to the server log, or just pass them to template context and show them in a html page, if that makes it easier for you to test in a production environment where SSL is enabled.

- `request.is_secure()`: if you're failing to get DRF to use `http`, chances are you are getting `False`.
- `request.META` gives you all headers that Django received. Did the header `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` show up? What value is it?

  - I want to share that this is the a-ha moment for me: the value of `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` is `https,https`, which tells me that it somehow having duplicated values, and I probably have `proxy_set_header` set twice, and Bingo! By default K8 ingress controller already has this line, and since I added it again through a `location-snippet`, now I have two lines of `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` in total. After removing my snippet, DRF shows `https` and I was so so happy to get this done. It wasn't that straight forward because I thought `proxy_set_header` will overwrite and "set" the header value. But seems like it just keep appending.

Comment: Hi this is helpful. But simply changing proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; to proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto; worked in my case. 
My settings are client -> http/https -> ALB -> http -> nginx -> http -> django, with nginx/django in same docker containers. I presume $scheme just forwards protocol that is passed to nginx, whereas $http_x_forwarded_proto contains original protocol from client through ALB.
Hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: @Bossam glad that you made it work! I think it's because in your case you are using AWS ALB, which will set `$http_x_forwarded_proto` for you. In my setting I am using my own nginx as load balancer, and my nginx is directly exposed to external traffic. I think this also explains why your nginx `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme` does not work, because your AWS ALB probably is directing all external traffic to http internally, so when your nginx is behind that ALB, your `$schema` will always be http, therefore you never get https in Django.

Comment: It definitely seems so!. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: This is an amazing answer. For me the route was NGINX -> Gunicorn -> Django all running within Docker instances. Setting `forwarded_allow_ips = '*'` in my Gunicorn config did the trick.

Comment: This solution did not work for me. I still have the pagination link going to https.

Comment: This helped a lot! I used `HTTP_X_SCHEME` in the end, but the other steps were needed as well. I have two nginx instances running. The first redirects `HTTP` to `HTTPS` and also routes different subdomains to different applications. The second one actually exposes the application and static files. So basically the first one would need to forward the scheme, which I did not need as it always redirects to `HTTPS` anyways.

Comment: I used `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https` to force the connection to https. Seems to work fine for me in an environment where one nginx container routes to another, which then routes to gunicorn/Django.

Answer (score 11):

> Do I need to set that Django SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER? I wasn't sure, given the warning that it's potentially insecure.

Yes you do.
However, you need to take care about what's your doing. In particular making sure it drop the X-Forwarded-Proto from outside.

Comment: Got it- so this requires both setting the X-Forwarded-Proto header as well as the Django setting? This part of web development/deployment is certainly a weak spot for me- how would I ensure the X-Forwarded-Proto from outside is dropped?

Comment: Hmm, I did add this setting & left the `proxy_set_header` line in my nginx config, but it still doesn't work. I'll keep testing with this configuration

Comment: @prof.phython I wasn’t, however it was pretty simple to use the majority of the url and add the https myself. I’m sure there’s some way to accomplish having DRF use https in the provided links but nothing in this question helped me get it working.

Comment: @dkhaupt okay. So you created the link yourself then?

Comment: Yes- this API was consumed by an Angular front end so I just made sure in that code that the url used includes HTTPS. I didn’t create the link in the backend.

Comment: okay. I guess i'll be doing the same thing, if could not get this working.

Answer (score -1):

This answer may not be the best one, but it works and there is no need to change nginx and django SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER.

in settings.py:

```
MY_PROTOCOL = "https"
```

in views.py:

```
from django.conf import settings

class MyView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
        if settings.MY_PROTOCOL == "https":
            if response.data["next"]:
                response.data["next"] = response.data["next"].replace(
                "http://", "https://"
            )
            if response.data["previous"]:
                response.data["previous"] = response.data["previous"].replace(
                "http://", "https://"
            )
        return response
```