# Django Rest Framework - Pagination data URL's showing http instead of https

Tags: django, rest, https, django-rest-framework

I am hitting on https://xyz.abcd.com/api/users&page=3 from browser.
But data I am getting consists of http URL's.

```
{
"count": 410,
"next": "http://xyz.abcd.com/api/users&page=4",
"previous": "http://xyz.abcd.com/api/users&page=2",
"results": [<data goes here>]
}
```

I have set `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True` in *`settings.py`*. However it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django rest framework https for absolute urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097643/django-rest-framework-https-for-absolute-urls)

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22284717/10170918) might be help you.

Comment: I just had this problem and wrote an answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57800775/9814131